# Copy file from a jar in a custom gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle

I write a custom gradle plugin where I would like to copy a specific file from a jar inside the classpath into the `buildDir`. I played around in a sandbox project and got this solution working:

```
task copyFile(type: Copy) {
            from zipTree(project.configurations.compile.filter{it.name.startsWith('spring-webmvc')}.singleFile)
            include "overview.html"
            into project.buildDir
        }
```

but if copy it into my plugin:

```
project.task(type: Copy, "copyFile") {
            from zipTree(project.configurations.compile.filter{it.name.startsWith('spring-webmvc')}.singleFile)
            include "overview.html"
            into project.buildDir
        }
```

I got the error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle-springdoc-plugin-test'.
> Could not find method zipTree() for arguments [/Users/blackhacker/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.0.RELEASE/jar/a82202c4d09d684a8d52ade479c0e508d904700b/spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar] on task ':copyFile'.
```

The result of

```
println project.configurations.compile.filter{it.name.startsWith('spring-webmvc')}.singleFile.class
```

is

```
class java.io.File
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike a build script, a plugin does not have an implicit `project` context (unless you give it one). Hence you'll have to use `project.task` rather than `task`, `project.zipTree` rather than `zipTree`, `project.file` rather than `file`, etc.

PS: In your case, it's important to use `project.zipTree { ... }` (note the curly braces) to defer searching for the file until the Zip contents are actually requested. Otherwise you risk slowing down each build invocation (even ones that never execute `copyFile`) and, if the file is being produced by the same build, even build failures (because the configuration is resolved before the file has been added).

Comment: Thx Peter! Seems you ´re a one stop ressource for gradle questions :-) I added a ```project.afterEvaluate```block here, otherwise I got a ```You can't change a configuration which is not in unresolved state!``` message.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. Sounds like you didn't use curly braces.